# Why do nested Divs come out of the parent in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, compatibility, html

Sorry, I don't have the exact code with me, but hopefully this works with the example I provide.

Why is it that in IE, some nested divs pop out and sit in the wrong place (example, 200px down from where it should be).

```
<div style="width:1024px;height:103px;background-color:green;">
    <div style="float:left;width:300px;height:103px;"><img src="LOGO URL"/>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;width:180px;height:103px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone understand what I mean? I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with double margins. Should I still bother making website compatible with IE7 and 6?

I'm trying to learn html the proper way. I want to be able to ensure my code is always compatible with all browsers and accessible to the disabled. Is there somewhere you would recommend that I can learn the "correct" practices? I understand most HTML, but compatibility can have issues.

Comment: Have you tried adding `white-space: nowrap;` on your top-level div?

Comment: Because they are being floated.

Comment: I can't reproduce, even in IE6: http://jsfiddle.net/UZYdQ/show/. You need to show us your actual code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your IE problem is most likely because float:right element is appeared after it's siblings. (see number 3 below).

Speaking about how to learn HTML and CSS best practices, I would recommend playing around with [CSS Zen garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) to see how different amazing designs are built using a "static" html.

Looking at the HTML I see following issues:

1. Specifying static width and height is not a good idea
2. float right element should appear before any other sibling (otherwise IE can not render it properly) - (this is most likely the issue).
3. Having float:left for the other element is not necessary
4. adding a clear:both in the end of all siblings will ensure that parent will expand in height (without the need to specify height)

so I would change your HTML to this:

```
<div>
    <div style="float:right;"></div>
    <div><img src="LOGO URL"/></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead your parent can expand in height naturally

Comment: Thank you very much valipour. I implemented what I learned from you into my theme and it worked great. I'm glad I have learned something.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work the same in a modern browser? Parent elements are never to expand to contain floated elements. To do what you want, you either need to float the parent or give it an 'overflow:auto' CSS property. But fixing the height of the parent div to 103px will still restrict things.

Comment: Each of the three `div`s has `height:103px`, so it's unlikely to be that.

Comment: @thirtydot - He says they "come out of the div" so I'm assuming he does some manipulation of values or content for that to happen.

Comment: @Rob - "come out of the div" was my problem exactly. overflow:auto; solved it fine. I think that was the problem here as well.

Comment: Floating the parent element worked for me, but `overflow: auto` did not.